# non static method cannot be referenced from static context - JAVA

Tags: java

i am trying to pass the value t from one class to another, but before i even run the program i get `non static method cannot be referenced from static context` from this line of code :

```
t = (PrinterSettings.getT() * 60);
```

i am trying to get the value t from this code :

```
public int t = 1; //defualt value for amount of mintues in the future the job should wait untill sent

public int getT() {
            return (t);
        }

 public void setT(int t) {
            this.t = t;
         }
```

what have i done wrong ? and how can i get t

EDIT :

Whole of my code where i get t from

```
         public int t = 1; //defualt value for amount of seconds in the future the job should wait untill sent

    public int getT() {
        return (t);
    }

    public void setT(int t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
```

and this is the class that i am using that calls t from the above class to use:

```
public class DealyTillPrint {

    public int t;

    public String CompletefileName;
    private String printerindx;
    private static int s;
    private static int x;
    public static int SecondsTillRelase;

    public void countDown() {
        System.out.println("Countdown called");
        s = 1; // interval 
    t = ((new PrinterSettings().getT()) * 60); //(PrinterSettings.SecondsTillRelase); // number of seconds
        System.out.println("t is : " + t);
        while (t > 0) {
            System.out.println("Printing in : " + t);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(s * 1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            t--;
        }
```

and here is where i set `t` using a spinner

```
<p:spinner min="1" max="1000" value="#{printerSettings.t}"  size ="1">
                    <p:ajax update="NewTime"/>
                </p:spinner>
```

Comment: `getT` isn't a static method, you need to create an instance of the class, or make it a static method.

Comment: So, where exactly are you calling for the spinner?

Comment: edited above to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to do 1 of 2 things:

1) Make everything in your PrinterSettings file static (and make PrinterSettings static as well):

```
public static int t = 1; 

public static int getT() {
            return (t);
        }

 public static void setT(int t) {
            this.t = t;
         }
```

2) Don't change PrinterSettings, and just do this for your code:

```
//Put this somewhere at the beginning of your code:
PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();

//Now have some code, which will include setT() at some point

//Then do this:
t = (printerSettings.getT() * 60);
```

In my opinion the latter would be more preferable.

EDIT: The edit that I just made is because if you don't keep a hold on the PrinterSettings variable that you were using, new-ing one up will have `t` be 1 in that new PrinterSettings object. Instead, make sure that you're instantiating an object of PrinterSettings at the beginning of your program, and just use that one the whole way through.

Comment: Thanks i have just tried your second suggestion, and although this has sorted out the error, the answer i get is always 60, even when t is changed using the spinner, i always get 60 any idea why ? thanks :)

Comment: I know why. Making an edit.

Comment: thanks i have just tried that but now i get the error `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop of some kind?

Comment: Nope, will post the whole of my code, but basically it should just be an spinner on an xhtml page that increases the count,

Answer (score 2):

You're using `PrinterSettings.getT()` but you can't do that because `PrinterSettings` is a class and the `getT()` method is for the object.  You need to create an object of PrinterSettings first, then you can call `getT()`.

```
PrinterSettings myObjectOfPrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
myObjectOfPrinterSettings.getT();  //this should work without the error
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
public int getT() {
            return (t);
        }
Write:

public static int getT() {
            return (t);
        }
```

This will solve your problem.
With this change you can access this method with its class name. As a class method.

Comment: Hmm, `t` is not static either ...

Comment: Thanks Henry, for the correction.